# Horrors of OnPointerDown versus OnBeginDrag in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, unity3d-ui

I'm concerned over the difference between `OnPointerDown` versus `OnBeginDrag` in single-finger movement code.

(In the latest Unity paradigm of using a physics raycaster: so, finally, Unity will properly ignore touch on the UI layer.

So from 2015 onwards what you must do is this:

1. Forget about the crap traditional `Input` or `Touches` system which are pointless crap and don't work
2. Add an empty game object with a usually BoxCollider2D, likely bigger than the screen. Make the layer called say "Draw". Physics settings, "Draw" interacts with nothing
3. Simply add to the camera, **a 2D or 3D physics raycaster**. Event mask the "Draw" layer.

[image]

Do a script like below and put it on.

(Tip - don't forget to simply add an `EventSystem` to the scene. Bizarrely, Unity does not do this automatically for you in some situations but Unity does do it automatically for you in other situations, so it's annoying if you forget!)

But **here's the problem**.

There has got to be some subtle difference between using `OnPointerDown` versus `OnBeginDrag` (and the matching end calls).  (You can just swap the action in the following code sample.)

Naturally Unity offers no guidance on this; the following code beautifully rejects stray grabs and also flawlessly ignores your UI layer (thanks Unity! at last!) but I am mystified about the difference between the two approaches (begin drag V. begin touch) and I cannot in anyway find the logical difference between the two in unit testing.

What's the answer?

```
/*

general movement of something by a finger.

*/

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class FingerMove:MonoBehaviour,
      IPointerDownHandler,
      IBeginDragHandler,
      IDragHandler,
      IPointerUpHandler,
      IEndDragHandler
  {
  public Transform moveThis;
  
  private Camera theCam;
  private FourLimits thingLimits;
  
  private Vector3 prevPointWorldSpace;
  private Vector3 thisPointWorldSpace;
  private Vector3 realWorldTravel;
  
  public void Awake()
    {
    theCam = Camera.main or whatever;
    }
  
  public void OnMarkersReady() // (would be EVENT DRIVEN for liveness)
    {
    thingLimits = Grid.liveMarkers. your motion limits
    }
  
  private int drawFinger;
  private bool drawFingerAlreadyDown;
  
  public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData data)
    {
    Debug.Log("    P DOWN "  +data.pointerId.ToString() );
    }
  
  public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData data)
    {
    Debug.Log("    BEGIN DRAG "  +data.pointerId.ToString() );
    
    if (drawFingerAlreadyDown == true)
      {
      Debug.Log("    IGNORE THAT DOWN! "  +data.pointerId.ToString() );
      return;
      }
    drawFinger = data.pointerId;
    drawFingerAlreadyDown=true;
    
    prevPointWorldSpace = theCam.ScreenToWorldPoint( data.position );
    }
  
  public void OnDrag (PointerEventData data)
    {
    Debug.Log("    ON DRAG "  +data.pointerId.ToString() );
    
    if (drawFingerAlreadyDown == false)
      {
      Debug.Log("    IGNORE THAT PHANTOM! "  +data.pointerId.ToString() );
      }
    
    if ( drawFinger != data.pointerId )
      {
      Debug.Log("    IGNORE THAT DRAG! "  +data.pointerId.ToString() );
      return;
      }
    
    thisPointWorldSpace = theCam.ScreenToWorldPoint( data.position );
    realWorldTravel = thisPointWorldSpace - prevPointWorldSpace;
    _processRealWorldtravel();
    prevPointWorldSpace = thisPointWorldSpace;
    }
    
  public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData data)
    {
    Debug.Log("    END DRAG "  +data.pointerId.ToString() );
    
    if ( drawFinger != data.pointerId )
      {
      Debug.Log("    IGNORE THAT UP! "  +data.pointerId.ToString() );
      return;
      }
    
    drawFingerAlreadyDown = false;
    }
  public void OnPointerUp (PointerEventData data)
    {
    Debug.Log("    P UP "  +data.pointerId.ToString() );
    }
  
  private void _processRealWorldtravel()
    {
    if ( Grid. your pause concept .Paused ) return;
    
   // potential new position...
    Vector3 pot = moveThis.position + realWorldTravel;
    
    // almost always, squeeze to a limits box...
    // (whether the live screen size, or some other box)
    
    if (pot.x < thingLimits.left) pot.x = thingLimits.left;
    if (pot.y > thingLimits.top) pot.y = thingLimits.top;
    if (pot.x > thingLimits.right) pot.x = thingLimits.right;
    if (pot.y < thingLimits.bottom) pot.y = thingLimits.bottom;
    
    // kinematic ... moveThis.position = pot;
    // or
    // if pushing around physics bodies ...  rigidbody.MovePosition(pot);
    }
  }
```

And here's a handy thing. Save typing with the same thing for 3D scenes, using the little-known but exquisite

## pointerCurrentRaycast

here's how... notice the excellent

```
data.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition
```

call courtesy Unity.

```
public class FingerDrag .. for 3D scenes:MonoBehaviour,
      IPointerDownHandler,
      IDragHandler,
      IPointerUpHandler
  {
  public Transform moveMe;
  
  private Vector3 prevPointWorldSpace;
  private Vector3 thisPointWorldSpace;
  private Vector3 realWorldTravel;
  
  private int drawFinger;
  private bool drawFingerAlreadyDown;
  
  public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData data)
    {
    if (drawFingerAlreadyDown == true)
      return;
    drawFinger = data.pointerId;
    drawFingerAlreadyDown=true;
    
    prevPointWorldSpace = data.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition;
    // in this example we'll put it under finger control...
    moveMe.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
    }
  
  public void OnDrag (PointerEventData data)
    {
    if (drawFingerAlreadyDown == false)
      return;
    if ( drawFinger != data.pointerId )
      return;
    
    thisPointWorldSpace = data.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition;
    
    realWorldTravel = thisPointWorldSpace - prevPointWorldSpace;
    _processRealWorldtravel();
    
    prevPointWorldSpace = thisPointWorldSpace;
    }
    
  public void OnPointerUp (PointerEventData data)
    {
    if ( drawFinger != data.pointerId )
      return;
    
    drawFingerAlreadyDown = false;
    moveMe.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
    moveMe = null;
    }
  
  private void _processRealWorldtravel()
    {
    Vector3 pot = moveMe.position;
    
    pot.x += realWorldTravel.x;
    pot.y += realWorldTravel.y;
    moveMe.position = pot;
    }
  }
```

Comment: To be fair I've not used OnPointerDown and  OnBeginDrag before because it was buggy when it came out about a year or two ago. I use raycast on mobile devices to detect touch on object. You want to know the difference between OnPointerDown and OnBeginDrag and when they should be used?

Comment: I copied your script into a test project, Unity 5.2.1. when i clicked the Box2D it logged the OnPointerDown stuff, when I started dragging it logged OnBeginDrag stuff. So if you click and hold but do not move than  OnPointerDown gets invoked, OnBeginDrag does not.

Comment: Hi Prog & Nikster.  Yes, I understand the difference as such, as Nika explains ... I guess I want to know *which one to use* ... in fact in the real world which one is the way to go?

Comment: @Programmer i put in an example of the super-handy **pointerCurrentRaycast** for 3D scene use.  Save typing

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I want to start by saying that `Input` and `Touches` are not crappy.They are still usefull and were the best way to check for `touch` on mobile devices before `OnPointerDown` and `OnBeginDrag` came along. `OnMouseDown()` you can call crappy because it was not optimized for mobile. For a **beginner** who just **started** to learn Unity, `Input` and `Touches` are their options.

As for your question, `OnPointerDown` and `OnBeginDrag` are **NOT** the-same. Although they  almost do the-same thing but they were implemented to perform in different ways. Below I will describe most of these:

`OnPointerDown`:
Called when there is press/touch on the screen (when there is a click or finger is pressed down on touch screen)

`OnPointerUp`:
Called when press/touch is released (when click is released or finger is removed from the touch screen)

`OnBeginDrag`:
Called **once** before a drag is started(when the finger/mouse is moved for the **first** time while down)

`OnDrag` :
Repeatedly called when user is dragging on the screen (when the finger/mouse is moving on the touch screen)

`OnEndDrag`:
Called when drag stops (when the finger/mouse is no **longer** moving on the touch screen).

**`OnPointerDown`** versus **`OnBeginDrag`** and **`OnEndDrag`**

`OnPointerUp` will **NOT** be called if `OnPointerDown` **has not been** called. `OnEndDrag` will **NOT** be called if `OnBeginDrag` **has not been** called. Its like the curly braces in C++,C#, you **open** it '**{**' and you **close** it '**}**'.

**THE DIFFERENCE**:
OnPointerDown will be called **once** and **immediately** when finger/mouse is on the touch screen. Nothing else will happen until there is a mouse movement or the finger moves on the screen then `OnBeginDrag` will be called **once** followed by OnDrag.

*These are made for doing advanced usage such such as **custom** UI with controls that is not included in Unity.*

**WHEN TO USE EACH ONE:**

**1.** When you have to implement a **simple click button**, for example, Up,Down, Shoot Button on the screen, you **only** need `OnPointerDown` to detect the touch. This should work for Sprite Images.

**2.** When you have to implement a custom **toggle switch** and you want it to be **realistic** so that the player can drag to left/right or up/down to **toggle** it then you need `OnPointerDown` ,  `OnBeginDrag` , `OnDrag` , `OnEndDrag` , `OnPointerUp`. You need to write your code in this order to have a **smooth** Sprite/Texture transition on the screen. Some toggle switches are made to be to **clicked** and it will **toggle**. Some people prefer to make it look realistic by making it so that you have to **drag** it in order to **toggle** it.

**3.** Also when you want to **implement** a Generic re-usable **pop-up window** that is draggable, you also need to use those 5 functions (`OnPointerDown` ,  `OnBeginDrag` , `OnDrag` , `OnEndDrag` , `OnPointerUp`).
First detect when there is a click(`OnPointerDown`), check to make sure that the Sprite clicked is the right one you want to move. Wait for player to move(`OnBeginDrag`) their finger/mouse. Once they start dragging, maybe you can call a coroutine function with `while` **loop** that will start moving the Sprite and inside that coroutine, you can **smooth** the movement of the Sprite with `Time.deltaTime` or any other preferred method.

Since `OnBeginDrag` is called once, it is a good place to **start** the **coroutine**.
As the player continue to drag the Sprite, `OnDrag` will be called **repeatedly**. Use the `OnDrag` function to get the current location of the finder and update that to a `Vector3` that the coroutine that is **already** running will use to **update** the **position** of the Sprite. When the player **stops** moving their finger/mouse on the screen, `OnEndDrag` is called and you can `boolean` variable and tell the coroutine to stop **updating** the position of the Sprite. Then, when the player **releases** their finger(`OnPointerUp`) you can then stop the coroutine with the StopCoroutine function.

Because of `OnBeginDrag` we we are able to start coroutine once drag started while waiting for drag to end. It **wouldn't** make **sense** to **start** that coroutine in `OnPointerDown` because that means that each time player **touches** the screen, a coroutine would be **started**.

Without `OnBeginDrag`, we have to use `boolean` variable to make the coroutine start only once in the `OnDrag` function which is called every time or else there would be coroutine running everywhere and unexpected movement of the Sprite will occur.

**4.** When you want to determine how long player moved their finger. Example of this is that famous game called **Fruit Ninja**. Lets just say you want to determine far the player swiped on the screen.

First, **wait** until `OnPointerDown` is  called, **wait** again until `OnBeginDrag` is called, then you can get the **current** position of the finger inside `OnBeginDrag` function because `OnBeginDrag` is called before the finger starts moving. After the finger is released,  `OnEndDrag` is called. Then you can get the current position of finger again. You can use these **two** **positions** to check how far the finger moved by **subtracting** them.

If you instead decide to use `OnPointerDown` as the place to get the **first** **position** of the finger, you will get a **wrong** result because if the player **swipes right**, then **waits** and **swipes left** then **waits** again and **swipe up** **without releasing their finger** after **each** swipe, the only **good** result you have is the **first swipe**(*right swipe*). The **left** and the **up** swipe will have **invalid** values because that first value you got when `OnPointerDown` was **called** is the value you are **still** using. This is because the player never removed their finger from the screen so **therefore**, `OnPointerDown` is **never** called **again** and the first old **old value** is still there.

But when you use `OnBeginDrag` instead of `OnPointerDown`, this problem will be **gone** because when the finger **stops moving**, `OnEndDrag` is called and when it starts moving again `OnBeginDrag`  is called once again causing the first **position** to be **overwritten** with the **new one**.

Comment: *"will not be called..."* pairing: astounding point, good one!

Comment: I realized my question was a bit quixotic, so i've closed it on this!  the point made here by @Programmer ... ***"OnEndDrag will NOT be called if OnBeginDrag has not been called. Its like the curly braces..."*** etc., seems to be the critical insight in this QA.  Thanks, all !

Comment: No problem Joe. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: dude @programmer how are you.  I've been thinking, what is the BEST WAY, lately, if you simply want to detect a touch (say, swipe) anywhere on the screen?  It's amazing something so basic is so vague in Unity.  What's your opinion?

Comment: What I mean is, I usually have to add a empty collider (just a flat box) under the camera (ie that moves around with the camera) to detect touches on the screen of the device.  I mean in a normal 3D game where the camera is on the move.  It seems inelegant.

Comment: That method doesn't sound good. What are going to do with the swipe data? It would be good to understand what exactly you are trying to do as there are many ways to detect swipe.

Comment: here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323677/using-unity3ds-ipointerdownhandler-approach-but-with-the-whole-screen  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `OnBeginDrag` doesn't get called until the touch/mouse has moved a certain minimum distance, the drag threshold. You can set the drag threshold on the Event System component.

This is necessary for when you have a hierarchy of objects with different ways of handling input, especially scrollviews. Imagine you have a scrollview with a vertical stack of cells, each with a button in it. When the touch first starts on one of the buttons, we don't know whether the user is tapping a button or dragging the scrollview. It isn't until the touch gets dragged for the drag threshold that we know it is a drag and not a tap.