# Can't get multitouch to work in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch, multi-touch

after searching for a solution I still can't figure out why my multitouch script in unity isn't working. This is my code. And before you ask: All variables do exist.

```
    void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase != TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position), Vector2.zero);
                if (hit.collider != null && hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "Links")
                {
                    cannon.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(cannon.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position + new Vector2(-0.1f, 0) * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
                }
                else if (hit.collider != null && hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "Rechts")
                {
                    cannon.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(cannon.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position + new Vector2(0.1f, 0) * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
                }
            }



            if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position), Vector2.zero);
                if (hit.collider != null && hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "Fire")
                {
                    clone = Instantiate(projectile, cannon.transform.position + new Vector3(0, 1.3f, 0), transform.rotation) as Rigidbody2D;
                    clone.velocity = new Vector2(0, speed);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It only registers one input at a time. Yes my phone does support multitouch. I'll appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Simply add Debug.Log lines to debug your code.  ... you will quickly find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is very simple !

You have a "0" were you should have an "i".  That's all it is.

You are looping through with i ...

```
    for (i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
```

sometimes you correctly refer to

```
     GetTouch(i)
```

but at other times you incorrectly refer to

```
    GetTouch(0)
```

fortunately that's all it is!

Don't forget you can easily solve such problems in the future by logging as you go (use Debug.Log, or, have a `Text` on the screen and write your development info there, `dev.text = "blah"` )

Comment: not at all, just a mistake.  doing "touch" is very tricky.  Note - you are going to have a problem **that actually, "touch" is deprecated! if you use it, it does not block touches on your buttons and other UI elements.  nowadays you have to do this...** long explanation http://stackoverflow.com/q/36048106/294884