# Equivalent of Input.GetMouseButton (0) in touch?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began` is the equivalent of `Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)`

`Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended` is the equivalent of `Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)`

What is the equivalent of `Input.GetMouseButton (0)`?

Comment: might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048106/horrors-of-onpointerdown-versus-onbegindrag-in-unity3d

Comment: @Dake. It's good you are learning how to use `Input.GetTouch`. Jerry's answer is  actually what you are looking for. If you want to detect one touch  down on the screen use `Input.touchCount == 1`. To detect multiple touches down on the screen, then use `Input.touchCount > 0`. That answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Input.touchCount > 0
```

but still depends what you really want. Maybe is better for you:

```
Input.touchCount == 1
```